# Set selected value for dropdown based on the display value in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how can I set the selected value for dropdown based on the display value in jquery/javascript

Example:

```
<select id='test'>
  <option value='sgf'>One</option>
  <option value='sdf'>Two</option>
  <option value='gfr'>Three</option>
  <option value='dfg'>Four</option>
</select>
```

How Can I set the selected to value based on the display value? Let say, I want to set the selected when display value is 'Three'

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to change the value 'gfr' to "Three" once selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#test option').filter(function () {
   return $(this).text() == 'Three';
})[0].selected = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#test option:contains(Three)").prop("selected", true)
```

assuming the words are sufficiently unique. Otherwise go with @Box9's approach for more robustness.

Comment: this doesnt seem work for me... error 'Object doesn't support this property or method' display

Comment: `prop` was introduced in jQuery 1.6 afaik. What version are you on?